# Are comments being deleted?

Tags: discussion

I might be making this up. But it seems that comments are disappearing here and there. I assume that they're just not up to snuff, but I haven't noticed other SE sites just deleting comments outright. (again, though, I might be dreaming this too...I've been known to not always pay attention ;)

Comment: I do this on UX as I peruse closed/old questions when there's no longer relevant comments

Answer (score 2):

I think this is my fault.

In general, comments can be removed for several reasons.  The bigger sites tend to be more strict about this but we don't do a lot of comment pruning here.

Typical reasons for removal:

- **Rude or offensive**
  We really don't get comments that fall under this banner (or at least I haven't seen any).
- **Not constructive / off-topic**
  I've deleted 2 comments for this reason:

  1. A comment asking mods to clean up a comment thread.  There really wasn't a reason to clean up the thread so I deleted his comment to avoid other mods wasting their time on it.
  2. A comment suggesting that another user was trolling.  I did some research and found this assertion to be unsupported<sup>1</sup> so I deleted it as noise.
- **Obsolete**
  I've deleted several comments in this category.  If a comment references content that is no longer in the question/answer, it is usually removed to avoid confusion.
- **Too chatty**
  We have many comments that fit this description, but we're a growing community so I don't see a problem leaving them.

So yes, comments have been deleted.  It's fairly rare, but comments get deleted when they distract from the real content.

---

<sup>1 *The only "evidence" of trolling was the question asker's display name.  However, the question content gave no indication of trolling; the user has accounts on other SE sites with many questions and answers and no evident instances of trolling; and the display name in question is a common dictionary word with no offensive meaning.*</sup>

Comment: Ah. Gotcha. I may not agree, but you have a valid argument for doing so.